# How to keep track of lines in a file python

Tags: python

I have the following file in python that I'm reading in and I want to keep track if the line is = [FOR_RECORD]. At that point I have a for loop populating an output with the value of [REG_NAME], until I reach the [/FOR_RECORD]. Then I want to go back to the start of the [FOR_RECORD] portion of the file to start populating with the next [REG_NAME]. How can I jump around in a python file like this?

Input file

```
--
--   generated with parser version 1.09
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

package [PKG_FILE]_pkg is

 [FOR_RECORD]
   constant [REG_NAME]_offset : std_logic_vector := x"[OFFSET]";
 [/FOR_RECORD]


 type [REG_NAME]_type is record
      [FILED_NAME]        : std_logic;               -- [OFFSET]     :
    end record [REG_NAME]_type;


 Package is [PKG_FILE]
```

Python code

```
for line in input_1:
    if '[FOR_RECORD]' in line:
        # This is where I want to jump to the next line
        #So I can evaluate the contents

    # I have 4 names in reg_name[i]
    #Very important that this is nested in the if statement
        for x in range(0,4):   
            if '[/FOR_RECORD]' in line:
                break
            if '[REG_NAME]' in line:
                line=line.replace('[REG_NAME]',reg_name[i]['name'])
                output.write(line)    

    output.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tell` to find your position in the file and `seek` to go to a specific position but you also have to use `readline` function because that for loop reads all of the lines first.

```
input1 = open('file')
eof = False
while (True):
    while (True):
        line = input1.readline()
        if line == '':
            eof = True
            break
        output.write(line)
        if '[FOR_RECORD]' in line:
            offset = input1.tell()
            break

    if eof: break
    for i in range(4):
        input1.seek(offset)
        while (True):
            line = input1.readline()
            if line == '':
                eof = True
                break
            if '[/FOR_RECORD]' in line:
                break
            if '[REG_NAME]' in line:
                line=line.replace('[REG_NAME]',reg_name[i]['name'])
                output.write(line)
    if eof: break
```

The first loop fins the position of `[FOR RECORD]` line and the second iterates over elements of reg_name.

Comment: Ok this is is great it gives me the 4 names I want in order. But how can I also print the rest of the file as well?

Comment: You can also store the position of `[/FOR_RECORD]` in another variable 
`if '[/FOR_RECORD]' in line:
    offset2=input1.tell()`
 and the seek to this position and start printing the rest of the file in another loop

Comment: Ok I want  to print out those values I got form you code, where they show up in the original file. How can I do this?

Comment: @rivera44 you mean you want to print the offsets?

Comment: The solution you provided prints all 4 elements of reg_name[i] which is great. Now I need to print the lines before it like use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

package [PKG_FILE]_pkg is. I need to print the entire input file, with the values of reg_name[i]

Comment: @rivera44 I've updated the code (I realized that you don't really need `offset2`) This should print all lines

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I wanted! But it can only detect one [FOR_RECORD] what if I have more later in the file? I think then, I would have an array of offset points, then wrap the wile loop in another sort of loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you're iterating over a file you can use the `next` command to advance the iterator (retrieve the next line).  So ... something like this probably gets you where you need:

```
for line in input_1:
  if '[FOR_RECORD]' in line:
    while '[/FOR_RECORD]' not in line:
      line = next(input_1)
      # your replacement code here.
```

This will iterate until it finds your begin tag, then continue to consume lines one by one until it finds your close tag, at which point you'll drop back to the outer `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you, that works but only for one value :/ I need to do replacement code more than once, therefore I have now looped my while '[/FOR' with a for loop for the amount of names in my array. But it only works with one value, do you want me to edit the question to be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mini state machine. If we are between a `[FOR_RECORD]` and `[/FOR_RECORD]` lines, we should do replacement, and not if outside. Code could be:

```
in_record = False
for line in input_1:
    if '[FOR_RECORD]' in line:
        in_record = True
    elif '[/FOR_RECORD]' in line:
        in_record = False
    elif in_record:
        if '[REG_NAME]' in line:
            for i in range(4):
                output.write(line.replace('[REG_NAME]',
                              reg_name[i]['name']))
        else: output.write(line)
    else: output.write(line)
```